# Next.js Link component not added to DOM with child component?

Tags: next.js, next-link

There's plenty of information about how to use Next.js' `Link` module if the child itself has an `<a>` tag within it (`passHref`), but there seems to be no indication that this should be needed for child component that aren't creating their own `<a>` tag. But I have run into a situation where a "decorator" component being a child of a `Link` component causes the link to not get rendered at all.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'

interface Props {
  children: string
}

// A simple functional component that transforms its child to more readable form
const HexString = ({ children: hex }: Props)  => {
  const shortHex = hex.substring(0, 8) + '...' + hex.substring(hex.length - 6)
  return (
    <span title={hex} className="hex-string">
      {shortHex}
    </span>
  )
}

// Page component wishing to use that decorator inside a Link
const MyPage: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/index">
        <HexString>0x0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f</HexString>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
export default MyPage
```

What gets rendered to the page is only the `hex-string` span and its contents. The `<a>` tag the `Link` is supposed to add is not in the DOM.

How can I get the `Link` component to properly render an anchor tag around this styled span tag from another component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difference in behavior between Next.js v12 and v13. Details about this change are in https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/36436. This is not yet in the documentation [because it's an "experimental" feature](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38819#issuecomment-1190470017))

In versions 12 and less, the behavior was to not include a literal anchor tag for `Link`:

```
// Renders: <strong onClick={nextLinkClickHandler}>Hello</strong>. No `<a>` is included.
<Link href="/about">
  <strong>Hello</strong>
</Link>


// Renders: <strong onClick={nextLinkClickHandler}>Hello</strong>. No `<a>` is included.
<Link href="/about">
  <CustomComponent />
</Link>
```

Note this happens when the child of a `Link` component is either a custom component (as this question shows) or an HTML tag.

In Next.js v13, this will be changing to always render an `<a>` anchor tag wrapped around those child components.

In Next.js v12, that behavior can be opted-into by setting the `experimental.newNextLinkBehavior` flag.

So, to ensure that an anchor tag is always present, either set `experimental.newNextLinkBehavior` to true (if using Next.js v12), or add an empty `<a>` tag around the child component:

```
// Page component wishing to use that decorator inside a Link
const MyPage: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/index">
        <a><HexString>0x0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f</HexString></a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue here is that the `Link` component cannot hav the `div` element as a parent. Remove the `div` tags encircling `Link` and you should be good.

Comment: The Link component renders itself as an anchor tag, and it's valid to have an anchor tag inside a div tag. The result is the same whether the Link element is the top level element returned, inside a div, paragraph, or list element container.